# When to use Series vs Asymptotic?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, asymptotics

I'm confused about the difference between `Series` and `Asymptotic`. Is there a good rule of thumb of when to use which?

Observations:

- Asymptotic of order $n+1$ is analogous to Series to order $n$
- Series generates constant terms

Code below uses both to simplify the following expression

$$\text{expr}=\frac{1}{\frac{s}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s}}{\pi -2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{s}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}}$$

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
expr = 1/(s/2 + (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s])/(\[Pi] - 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[s]/Sqrt[2]]));
SF = StringForm;
series[order_] := Normal@Series[expr, {s, 0, order}];
asymp[order_] := Asymptotic[expr, {s, 0, order}];
{approxSeries, approxAsymp} = 
  Table[{i, #[i]}, {i, 0, 3}] & /@ {series, asymp};

visualize[approx_, label_] := (
  Print[TableForm[approx, TableHeadings -> {{}, {"order", "expr"}}]];
  LogLogPlot @@ {{expr}~Join~(Last /@ approx), {s, 0., .2},
    PlotLegends -> {"true"}~Join~(SF["order ``", First@#] & /@ approx),
    PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Opacity[.5]}, Automatic, Dashed, Dotted, 
      DotDashed},
    PlotLabel -> label}
  )
Quiet[visualize[approxSeries, "Series"]]
Quiet[visualize[approxAsymp, "Asymptotic"]]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code produces a warning "Asymptotic::aord: Approximation order specification 0 should be a positive integer or Infinity." omitted by you.

Comment: Also the question arises: what is the result without `Quiet`s?

Comment: The constant in the result of `Series`  follows from `Limit[1/(
  s/2 + (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s])/(\[Pi] - 
    2 ArcTan[Sqrt[s]/Sqrt[2]])) - \[Pi]/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s]), s -> 0 ]` which results in `-1 - \[Pi]^2/4`. This term is not of importance for the asymptotic.

Comment: I've always wonder this myself too. I think 1. To avoid the `SeriesData` output and 2. `Asymptotic` generalizes `Series` in that it will give an expression asymptotic to the input. `Series` gives a (generalized) power series, and when this exists it's asymptotic to the input. Compare `Asymptotic[PrimePi[x], {x, ∞, 3}]` and `Series[PrimePi[x], {x, ∞, 3}]`.

Comment: The Properties & Relations section in `Asymptotic` says "Asymptotic typically gives the leading term in the series expansion". So usually the outputs will be super similar, and so I agree it's kind of confusing why both functions exist.

Comment: `Asymptotic` is meant as a more powerful ["superfunction"](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2020/03/in-less-than-a-year-so-much-new-launching-version-12-1-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/#the-asymptotic-superfunction). It can also handle, for example, inactivated operators (`Asymptotic[Inactive[Integrate][Exp[x^2], x], x -> 0]`). For a more detailed discussion about the peculiarities of implementation, I suggest watching [Live CEOing Ep 279: Calculus & Algebra Features for WL 12.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Eb1SN5uIc4&list=PLxn-kpJHbPx14mHrB5BlhImVOWo5Geg6f&index=444).

Answer (score 5):

The definition of `Asymptotic` can be accessed by `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal ``, and it seems that part of its code  actually depends on `Series`.

For example, under the context `` Asymptotics`AsymptoticDump` `` , the dependency is like

```
Asymptotic>ccAsymptotic>iAsymptotic>UnivariateAsymptotic>UnivariatePowerSeries
```

and

```
Asymptotics`AsymptoticDump`UnivariatePowerSeries//GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal
```

gives

```
...
resser = SeriesCoefficient[f, {x, x0, n}]
...
```

This can also be seen by

```
On[Series::esss]
Block[{Quiet},
Asymptotic[Exp[-1/x], {x, 0, 1}]
]
```

[image]

and as suggested by @MichaelE2,

```
Trace[Asymptotic[Exp[-1/x],{x,0,1}],_Series,TraceInternal->True]

(*{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{Series[x,{x,0,1}]}}}}}}}}}}}}}},{{{{{{{Series[E^(-1/x),{x,0,1}]}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}*)
```

Comment: How do you explain the difference between `Asymptotic[Log[a*x], {x, Infinity, 2}, Assumptions -> a > 0]` which results in `Log[a x]` and `Series[Log[a*x], {x, Infinity, 2}, Assumptions -> a > 0] // Normal` which outputs `Log[a] + Log[x]` (in 13.2.1)?

Comment: @Lacia, The series commands may also be seen in `Trace[
 Asymptotic[Exp[-1/x], {x, 0, 1}],
 _Series,
 TraceInternal -> True]`

Comment: @user64494 maybe because there are lots of conditions and preprocess before `SeriesCoefficient ` in the code of `Asymptotic`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes, I agree. It surprises me that the source code of `Asymptotic` is not fully protected.

Comment: @Lacia: Sorry, I dislike speculations. `Trace[Asymptotic[Log[a*x], {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> a > 0], _Series, 
 TraceInternal -> True]` results in `{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{Series[x,{x,0,1}]}}}}}}}}}}}}}},{{{{{{{Series[Log[a x],{x,0,1}]}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}` suggesting that no assumption is taken into account.

Comment: @user64494 why not look at the source code?

Comment: @Lacia: The question is "When to use Series vs Asymptotic?".  For `expr` from the question  both are equivalent, but, if we deal with parameters, I find `Series` preferable in view of the example presented by me.

Comment: @user64494 1) I did not suggest that `Asymptotic` is or is not better than `Series`. I only pointed out that `Asymptotic` depends on `Series`. 2) I am not interested in your example, since personally I don't trust the result of MMA when branch cut is involved - there are lots of bugs due to improperly dealing with branch cut.

Comment: @Lacia: Agreed with you concerning results with branch cuts.